# Joomla session timeout not working for my profile page in Joomla3

Tags: php, session, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am facing the strange behavior of Joomla session timeout. I have set the session timeout limit to 5 min from the back-end global configuration. As far as I know Joomla session setting   will work for both the front-end and back-end , but I read about the same in some forum they said it only worked for back-end. Which from my point of view is wrong because as I said I have set the session time out for 5 min and logged in to both front end (Home page) and back-end(control panel) and do nothing for at least for 5-6 min. After that time I am logged out from both the end. But if I repeat the same process and redirect to my profile page from front-end and back-end (control panel). So after the 5-6 min I logged out from back-end but not in front-end. I don't get this what is happening. If some has any suggestion about or having the same problem before please help me to figure out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Many Joomla pages (especially those with a form) will run a 'keepalive' javascript that periodically hits the server, keeping your session alive. This is because you wouldn't want your session to timeout while you were in the middle of filling out a form.

If you really want to disable this feature, there's a line in `components/com_users/views/profile/tmpl/edit.php` like: `JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');`. You can remove that (or better, override the template file and remove it there) and your users will inconveniently time out even if they are trying to fill out a form.